# Python float equality weirdness

Tags: python, floating-point, equality

Seeing some unexpected behavior with Python tonight.  Why is the following printing out 'not equal'?!

```
num = 1.00
num -= .95
nickel = .05

if nickel != num:
    print 'not equal'
else:
    print 'equal'
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Great stuff guys.  Been around for a while and never ran into it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[What every computer scientist should know about floating point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

```
>>> num = 1.00
>>> num
1.0
>>> num -= 0.95
>>> num
0.050000000000000044
>>> nickel = .05
>>> nickel
0.05
```

Answer (score 2):

You might find the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module useful.

```
>>> TWOPLACES = Decimal(10) ** -2
>>> Decimal(1).quantize(TWOPLACES)-Decimal(0.95).quantize(TWOPLACES) == Decimal(0.05).quantize(TWOPLACES)
True
```

Or, alternatively:

```
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 2
decimal.Decimal(1.00) - decimal.Decimal(0.95)
```

I inferred from your naming of the `nickel` variable that you were thinking about money.  Obviously, floating point is the wrong Type for that.

Comment: I disagree, it's the same problem. `>>> Decimal(.05) == Decimal(1.00 - .95) >>> False`

Comment: `Decimal('1') - Decimal('.95') == Decimal('.05')` or `Decimal(str(1.00 - .95)) == Decimal('.05')`

Comment: @jb. It's the same problem because you've converted the result of a floating point operation to a decimal. You need to have the operation done on decimals. You also have to be careful assigning decimals from floats. Note the difference between `Decimal(0.1)` and `Decimal('0.1')`

Answer (score 0):

This is a common floating point problem with computers. It has to do with how the computer stores floating point numbers. I would suggest giving [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) a quick read through.