# Python weird addition bug

Tags: python, floating-point, addition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python - decimal place issues with floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286061/python-decimal-place-issues-with-floats)
>   [Python float equality weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560832/python-float-equality-weirdness)

In the code below I have the variable `percentage` which is a float. I have it set up so that the if `number` reaches `10,000`, `percentage` is suppose to go up by `.01`.

```
# Tries to find a number that when squared and 5%'ed is still a square.

import math

print("Script has started:\n")

percentage = .1
number = 1
while number != -1:
    number = number + 1
    num_powered = number ** 2
    num_5per = num_powered * percentage
    num_5per_sqrt = math.sqrt(num_5per)
    num_list = list(str(num_5per_sqrt))
    dot_location = num_list.index(".")
    not_zero = 0
    for x in num_list[dot_location + 1:]:
        if x != "0":
            not_zero = 1
            break
    if not_zero == 0:
        print("*********************************")
        print("Map :",number)
        print("Safe-Area :",num_5per_sqrt)
        print("Percentage :",percentage)
        print("*********************************")
        input()

    if number > 10000:
              number = 0
              percentage = percentage + .01
              print(percentage)
```

Output:

```
0.11
0.12
0.13
0.14
0.15000000000000002  # Here is where it goes crazy
0.16000000000000003
```

Comment: This is incredibly common. Floating point numbers in the computer are base 2, and they can't precisely represent many numbers that are natural in base 10.

Comment: This is NOT a bug. It is a consequence of how floating point variables work. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html . Voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: oh I see thanks then sorry googled but didn't see duplicate.

Comment: This misunderstanding is so common it is actually mentioned not only in the [stackoverflow wiki on floating-point](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/floating-point/info), but also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [the Python docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

> Note that this is in the very nature of binary floating-point: this is **not a bug in Python, and it is not a bug in your code either** (emphasis mine). You’ll see the same kind of thing in all languages that support your hardware’s floating-point arithmetic (although some languages may not display the difference by default, or in all output modes)

You should probably use [the `decimal` module](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html).

Comment: That link is an incredibly nice explanation of the phenomenon, I'd never seen it before. I suggest anybody still confused should read it in its entirety.

Answer (score 9):

You are using floating point numbers and have experienced a [representation error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error). In particular, 0.01 has no exact representation as a binary floating point number. Instead a number very close to, but not exactly equal to 0.01 will be stored. This is not a bug. This is just the way floating point arithmetic works.

You can solve your problem in a few ways.

- Accept that the results are not completely accurate or
- Multiply everything by 100 and working with integers or
- Use the `Decimal` type.

Example:

```
from decimal import Decimal
percentage = Decimal('0.1')
step = Decimal('0.01')
percentage += step
```

Comment: +1 for the listing of common ways of addressing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Floats do not have infinite precision, and so you get weird behaviour like this.

A better solution would be to store your percentage as an integer, representing tenths of a percent and increment by one.

e.g.:

```
percent_as_integer += 1
```

instead of

```
percent_as_float += 0.01
```

When you want to display the percentage, simply do:

```
print "%d.%02d" % divmod(percent_as_integer, 100)
```

EDIT: Actually, using the decimal module instead as was suggested in another answer is probably a better, more pythonic solution.

Answer (score 1):

As described in other answers, this is a limitation of native floating point numbers in all current microprocessors.

If you need exact representation of decimal numbers (ex. for accounting and business application) you should use [decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) type, not floating point. You may also use [cdecimal](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cdecimal/2.3) module, which is a high-performance implementation of the decimal type.

Update:
Starting with Python v3.3, the builtin decimal module is implemented in C.