# python search float return wrong because of precision problem?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, floating-point, precision

I want to find a float in a arry like this:

```
arr = np.asarray([1351.1 , 1351.11, 1351.14, 1351.16, 1351.17])
index = np.searchsorted(arr, 1351.14, side="right") - 1 # return 2
```

But I find that it return wrong like this:

```
index = np.searchsorted(arr, 1351.1 + 0.04, side="right") - 1 # return 1
```

Because I want to search value like this:

```
indexes = np.searchsorted(arr, arr[0] + np.arange(10) * 0.01, side="right") - 1  # this will be wrong because of the problem above
```

Comment: Have you considered searching for the *closest* value to the target (e.g., by using `searchsorted` on the array `0.5 * (arr[1:] + arr[:-1])` of midpoints of `arr`)?

Comment: @MarkDickinson as you see, at last I want to search `np.searchsorted(arr, arr[0] + np.arange(10) * 0.01, side="right") - 1`, maybe your solution a little bit comple

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is due to the [representation error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error).

In my attempts,
as `1351.14 * 10000 == 13511400.000000002` and `(1351.1 + 0.04) * 10000 == 13511399.999999998`, `1351.14 != 1351.1 + 0.04`. You can see some extra information on this in Python in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873046/python-weird-addition-bug).

For a quick fix I tried to replace `1351.1 + 0.04` with `round(1351.1 + 0.04, 2)` and it seem to work (return 2), although I am not sure this is the best method.

Comment: `round` won't work consistently unless you apply it to both the numbers in the array and the number you're searching.

Answer (score 0):

As @dm2 suggested, forcing the precision on the second expression can be a solution. Forcing the values to float32 seems to work. But I ask someone with a better understanding of arithmetic operations in numpy to give a detailed answer.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.asarray([1351.1 , 1351.11, 1351.14, 1351.16, 1351.17],dtype=np.float32)
index = np.searchsorted(arr, np.float32(1351.1 + 0.04), side="right") - 1 
print(index)
```

Comment: are you sure? you result is still `1`, it should be `2`

Comment: You are right, my bad. I'll edit the answer then. What happened is that I had force it to float32 and assumed it would work with float64. I still think someone with a better knowledge of numpy arithmetic operations should help us here.